# How can I remove first and last character from each record in a delimited file in Windows?

Tags: regex, string, windows, batch-file

I have a delimited data file that I export from a Sybase IQ database. It has a quote in the begining and end of each record in the data file. The data itself is tab delimited e.g.

```
    'Name <tab> Address <tab> Phone'
    'Name <tab> Address <tab> Phone'
    'Name <tab> Address <tab> Phone'
```

I want to remove the first and last character i.e the single quote. I don't care about single quotes occurring embedded within any record in the data file.

I tried something like this based on answers on this site:

```
    @echo off
    Set "InputFile=oldfile.dat"
    Set "OutputFile=newfile.dat"

    setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion > "%OutputFile%"

    for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%InputFile%")
    do (
        set variable=%%a
        set variable=%variable:~0,+1!
        set variable=%variable:~0,-1!
        echo.%variable
    >> "%OutputFile%" 
    )
```

But I get a 'Syntax of the command is not correct' error message.

Comment: If you `don't have powershell`, why ask for Powershell solution on the title and use the `powershell` tag too? So which is it, Batch or Powershell?

Comment: @VonPryz --> My apologies for the misleading headline. It was late in the nite and I was trying to post the query and got stumped by the constant prompts around restrictions for using tags and stuff. What I meant was "No Powershell" solution i.e. Windows batch only.

Comment: Do you need to do this repeatedly or can you just open it once in a text editor and search/replace ^' and '$ ?

Answer (score 1):

A Batch file can not accurately process certain data, so the best method to solve this problem is using an hybrid Batch-JScript file, like dbenham's JREPL.BAT.

However, you don't need hundreds of lines of code to perform a replacement as simple as this one. The small Batch-JScript hybrid file below achieve this replacement and is simple enough so you may understand it and introduce small modifications, even if you know nothing about JScript. Save this file with .BAT extension.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setLocal
Set "InputFile=oldfile.dat"
Set "OutputFile=newfile.dat"

cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0" < "%InputFile%" > "%OutputFile%"

goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

while ( ! WScript.Stdin.AtEndOfStream ) {
   WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(WScript.Stdin.ReadLine().slice(1,-1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "InputFile=oldfile.dat"
Set "OutputFile=newfile.dat"

> "%OutputFile%" (
    for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%a in ("%InputFile%") do (
        set "variable=%%~a"
        set "variable=!variable:~1!"            remove the 1st character
        set "variable=!variable:~0,-1!"         remove the last character
        echo.!variable!
    )
)
```

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (helpful particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~a` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (special page) [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- (`!variable:~1!` etc.) [Extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)
- (`> "%OutputFile%"` special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: You could save a `set` command and say `set "variable=!variable:~1,-1!"`

Comment: This will corrupt any line that contains `!`. Probably not an issue with the OP's data, but it is a limitation that should be noted. Can be fixed by toggling delayed expansion ON and OFF within the loop. This will also delete empty lines, which is also probably not an issue.

Comment: @JosefZ:  I will try this and let you know how it worked. Thanks much !.

Comment: @SomethingDark: ... or even two: `echo.!variable:~1,-1!`

Answer (score 0):

Like most any other text file modifying task, this can be solved easily and efficiently using [JREPL.BAT - a regular expression find and replace utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). JREPL is pure script (hybrid JScript/batch) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is available from the command line via `jrepl /?`, or `jrepl /??` for paged output.

```
jrepl "^'(.*)'$" "$1" /f "oldfile.txt" /o "newfile.txt"
```

You can have the output overwrite the original by specifying `-` as the output file.

```
jrepl "^'(.*)'$" "$1" /f "file.txt" /o -
```

JREPL is a batch file, so you must use CALL JREPL if you put the command within another batch script.

Comment: I have a restriction around using third party utilities or software even if they are simple and free unfortunately. Hence my request for a solution using Batch commands and not using powershell also. Thanks for the suggestion on jrepl though. It will be useful in other cases.

Comment: @AJay - That is unfortunate. I also have restrictions at work - I cannot download 3rd party exe files. But I am able to create and run JScript and batch file scripts. JREPL is nothing but a batch file that also runs JScript, so I have no problem. The link provides the full script for JREPL. All you need to do is copy the code and paste it into your text (script) editor. I don't see how the powers that be can differentiate a batch script that you wrote from one that you copied from the internet. So perhaps you can use JREPL after all.

Comment: Hi @dbenham. I will try it as you said because I can certainly copy and paste text into file and run it. Thanks much !.